# Format legend text in R leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet, shiny

Is there a way to add line breaks to the title text of a legend in a R Leaflet panel? If the title is long I'd like to stack the text instead of stretching the legend across the screen. Can't find any options with the `addLegend()` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `<br>` where you want your title to line-break. i.e.

```
Here is <br> a long <br> title
```